LIS2DE12 configuration for interrupt when going from stillness to motion and vice versa
I'm having difficulties understanding how to configure the LIS2DE12 for generating interrupts. Especially the filter part is obscure to me.
The task is to make the accelerometer generate an interrupt when the device changes from being still to moving or the opposite.
The power consumption should be as low as possible, so an ODR of 1hz has been chosen, and also smaller movement should be filtered out. That means the device should have been moving for at least 5 minutes after having being still or vice versa before generating an interrupt.
Here is a link to the datasheet: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lis2de12.pdf
This is the register setup so far, and the once I don't understand what I should set to:
REG1: ODR (1Hz), LPen enabled, Zen/Yen/Xen enabled
REG2: help is needed
REG3: IA1 interrupt in INT1 pin enabled, everything else disabled
REG4: BDU continuous update, FS -+2G
REG5: BOOT normal, FIFO disabled, help is needed LIR_INT1, D4D_INT1
REG6: Everything disabled
REFERENCE: help is needed
INT1_CFG: help is needed
INT1_THS: help is needed
INT1_DURATION: 300 [s]
I hope someone is able to help.
Thanks.
